# Assign a variable to increment and refer to a series of label

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

How would one go about assigning a label control's ".Text" property to a variable. For example

when X = 1 it refers to Label1.Text.

when X = 2 it refers to Label2.Text

I ask because I want to update the .Text property of different labels, each of which are associated with an array of values, depending on the value of the corresponding array section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array containing a reference to the labels and access it via the index of the label you want:

```
var labels = new [] { Label1, Label2, Label3 }

labels[i].Text = "Foo";
```

Things to note - the index starts at 0 whereas your labels start at 1 so `labels[0]` is `Label1`

Comment: WHOA! I didn't realize that I could reference label controls and other things in an array. But that immediately makes this tic tac toe program Im working on so much more simple!!! Thank you! I used a super long switch/case to update my grid of labels but I knew there had to be an easier way! This has stumped me for so long!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple conditional logic:

```
string labelText;
if(x==1){
  labelText = Label1.Text;
}
else if (x==2){
  labelText = Label2.Text;
}
```